# Indexing an array from the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am learning Javascript and I come from a Python background.
So, it's fairly intuitive to me to try and index an `array` from the end i.e using negative indices.
From what I have read so far, Javascript doesn't support them.
However, I found something which seems interesting but I am unable to understand the reason behind this.

```
todos = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

function updateTodos(index, new_value) {
    todos[index] = new_value
    console.log(todos)
}

function deleteTodos(index) {
    todos.splice(index)
    console.log(todos)
}

deleteTodos(-1)    
updateTodos(-1, 'new_item')
deleteTodos(-1)
```

Output

```
["item1", "item2"]
["item1", "item2", -1: "new_item"]
["item1", -1: "new_item"]
```

Q: Why is `deleteTodos` able to delete the correct by index while `updateTodos` isn't?

Q: How can I accommodate for this behavior of negative indexing in `updateTodos` and any function dealing with the `array` data structure in general?

As far as I can make out, the indexing in `updateTodos` looks for the `index` variable and update the value at that index, if it exists, else, it creates a key-value pair. The `splice` method supports negative indexing, doesn't it?

I would appreciate if you can clarify my reasoning and/or help me with useful resources to understand this concept better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN, splice does support negative indexing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

> Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater
>   than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the
>   length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from
>   the end of the array (with origin 1).

So, that's why deleting works.

To enable negative indexing in update, you could check if the supplied argument is negative. If it is, it is a simple manner of using `array.length + index` to have the python-like indexing.

Comment: Thanks. My ad-hoc solution was to check if the index was negative and apply the formula you have written above but I am looking for a built-in functionality which can perform the update. Is there one?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality for reverse-indexing an array.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to add to the accepted answer:

1) Remember that when using splice that if you don't specify an amount of items to delete (second argument) then *everything from the index you specify to the end of the array will be deleted.* From your question I doubt this is what you want.

2) Splice can also be used to add elements to an array (third argument, fourth argument etc.) so would work fine for your update function.

A complete example to fix both issues would be like this:

```
function updateTodos(index, new_value) {
  todos.splice(index, 1, new_value);
}

function deleteTodos(index) {
  todos.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You could get even fancier and combine them both into one function where if you specify a value then that gets updated else it gets deleted, but it's probably unnecessary.